# How does "would" work in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

I'm confused because the entire sentence is present. Why does the writer suddenly talk about the past?

> (to) Seal
>
> This verb originally meant to close a letter’s envelope by using wax
> and a ‘seal‘ or stamp. It came to mean ‘to finish’, as in finish some
> business: you write the letter, put it in an envelope, and seal it:
> the process is finished. Now, we often use ‘seal‘ in business. For
> example when you say to seal a deal, it means to agree a business
> deal.
>
> In football it can mean to progress to the next stage in a competition
> or to decide a position in the table. In Tuesday’s (12 July) 2022
> Women’s Euros match from Group B, Germany sealed top spot by beating
> Spain 2-0. Here is The Guardian’s headline: ‘Popp seals top spot as
> Germany see off Spain to secure Euro 2022 progress.’
>
> Example: ‘Dazzling England demolish Norway 8-0 to seal Euro
> 2022 quarter-final spot‘ (The Guardian, 11 July 2022)
>
> Notice that in both these examples, the headlines us ‘spot‘ – ‘sealed
> top spot‘ and ‘seal quarter final spot‘. Spot means position, place
> and often goes with the verb ‘to seal‘. A different verb for this
> **would be** ‘secure’ – to secure a place in the quarter finals, to secure a spot in the semis, or secure a berth in the final.

Speaker A is asking a question, then B answers it by using "would".

A: can I use "would not have" in the dialogue below made by me :

- Why was the house in such a mess ? Did you do this ?
- No, I would not have done that, It's true that I was in the house but I would not have done that.

B: You could say "I would not have done that," but it **would** also be fine to just say "I wouldn't do that," since in effect you're making a general statement about your customary behavior.

My question is why the writer suddenly talking about past tense? Shouldn't it be "will?"

Comment: Does "would" is a past here? I'm confused because the entire sentence is present. Why does the writer suddenly talk about the past?

Comment: It's not the past tense use of "would" but its modal remoteness use, more specifically its tentative use.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what do mean by "more specifically its tentative use? Moda remoteness use? What is it?

Comment: Speaker A is asking a question, then B answers it by using "would". Is "would" conditional here?

A: can I use "would not have" in the dialogue below made by me :

Why was the house in such a mess ? Did you do this ?
No, I would not have done that, It's true that I was in the house but I would not have done that.
B: You could say "I would not have done that," but it would also be fine to just say "I wouldn't do that," since in effect you're making a general statement about your customary behavior.

Comment: Idiomatically, ***will*** is extremely unlikely in the exact cited context. The "future" (morphologically, not semantically) verb form *would* be a natural alternative in related contexts, such as ***That will be John at the door*** if a knock is heard around the time John is expected to arrive. But not here, where *a different verb **would** be 'secure'* is precisely equivalent to *'secure' **is** a different verb*. Note that the "inversion" of word sequence in my alternative is also irrelevant to the meaning - these are just stylistic choices.

Comment: Idiomatically, will is extremely unlikely in the exact cited context. The "future" (morphologically, not semantically) verb form **would be** a natural alternative in related contexts. I notice you use "would" here. How does it work in your sentence?

Answer (score 3):

*Is "would" the past tense here?* No, it's the conditional. The sentence implies that, if you wished to use a different verb instead of *seal*, that would be *secure.*

Comment: I think there is no conditional  sentence in those sentences. The writer directly uses "would". The writer is just giving an expalaination about the word "seal". And also there is no sentence "if you wished to use a different verb". That is confusing me.

Comment: I said that "if you wished to use a different verb" was the _implied_ meaning. Call it a hypothetical if you prefer. We say "Another option _would be_ to do this", meaning that suggestion B could be followed if A is not acceptable.

Comment: That's clear now. You explained "We say "another option would be to do this", meaning suggestion B could be followed if A is not acceptable". Is this also an implied  condition? Another option would be to do this,.. What is the uspoken condition?

Comment: "If A is not acceptable", of course. I was imagining people discussing a possible course of action (A), and someone saying something like "Or B would be another possibility", meaning that they could do B instead of A if they thought it was a better plan.

Comment: If so, what is the difference with "is?" Another way of saying this is... Or Another way of saying this would be...

Comment: _Would be_ makes it more of a suggestion - a 'tentative use', as Bill J. says

Comment: Thank you. What wouldnyou choose "would be" or "is" in context like this?

Comment: _Is_ states a fact ('tee shirt' is another way to spell 'T-shirt'), _would be_ offers a suggestion, as I explained.

Comment: So it depends on the speaker what they  choose "is" or "would" , doesn't it? Both are correct. tee shirt' is another way to spell 'T-shirt. Or tee shirt' would be another way to spell 'T-shirt